# Generate UK postcode from lat,lon search in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, postal-code

I'm trying to generate a UK postcode from a latitude and longitude search in Google Maps. For example, a search for 57.350237,-1.977539 in Google Maps returns this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSULM.png

I want to be able to extract that postcode - AB41 8.

All I've seen so far are ideas on how to get the lat,lon from the postcode but not the other way around. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a look at Google's Geocoding API, specifically [Reverse Geocoding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding).

Comment: Thanks, had a look at that and it's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in the UK, the Royal Mail are the only ones with such data of that accuracy and completeness.

To access it, you have to pay them for a copy of their [Postcode Address File](http://www2.royalmail.com/marketing-services/address-management-unit/address-data-products/postcode-address-file-paf?campaignid=paf_redirect).

Comment: How about the Ordnance Survey's [Code-Point Open](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/code-point-open/index.html) data? It doesn't contain full address data like the PAF, but it does contain a mapping between postcodes and latitudes/longitudes, as the OP requires.

Comment: @LukeH Good spot, interesting. You're right, that would be adequate for OP's needs.

Comment: Thanks for the input there. I'll explore that possibility too.